# Null reference when switching between forms

Tags: c#, gridview, null, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a program that has a main form with a DevExpress XtraGrid control. It has many rows with data from my DB. I have an Edit form and an edit button on the main form to edit the selected row. I was able to pull the info for the selected object into the Edit form fine, but for some reason I am having trouble doing it again when I run the UPDATE command. I'm referring to the selected row on my main form as `gridView1.GetFocusedRow()` and this worked perfectly for my showAttributes method, but no longer works.

My code follows. It is returning an exception because 'call' is null. Just to note a few things: I've tried doing `main.gridView1.Focus()` and `main.gridView1.FocusRowHandle(0)` if I'm just editing the first row - neither fixed the problem. This seems to tell me that the row is still focused correctly but the reference was lost somehow.

**In Main.cs**

```
    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is the key, that lets you access an attribute of the selected row. 
        Object obj = gridView1.GetFocusedRow();

        //1) Show NewEdit Form
        Edit edit = new Edit();
        edit.Show();

        //2) Display properties of this object from DB
        edit.showAttributes(obj);
    }
```

**In Edit.cs:**

```
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main main = new Main();
        Object obj = main.gridView1.GetFocusedRow();
        try
        {
            performUpdate(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }

    public void performUpdate(Object call1)
    {
        Main main = new Main();
        CallLog call = new CallLog();
        call = call1 as CallLog;

        executeSQLUpdate(call.Oid);
        main.xpServerCollectionSource1.Reload();
    }
```

**Here is the showAttributes code - does the same thing but works**

```
    public void showAttributes(Object call1)
    {
        try
        {
            Main main = new Main();
            CallLog call = new CallLog();
            call = call1 as CallLog;

            txtCompany.Text = call.CompanyName;
            txtFirst.Text = call.FirstName;
            txtMiddle.Text = call.MiddleName;
            txtLast.Text = call.LastName;
            txtPhone.Text = call.PhoneNumber;
            txtFax.Text = call.Fax;
            txtEmail.Text = call.Email;
            txtAttention.Text = call.Attention;
            txtCareOf.Text = call.CareOf;
            txtAddress1.Text = call.Address1;
            txtAddress2.Text = call.Address2;
            txtCity.Text = call.City;
            txtState.Text = call.State;
            txtZip.Text = call.ZipCode;
            txtProvince.Text = call.Province;
            txtCountry.Text = call.Country;
            txtMessage.Text = call.Message;
            txtResponse.Text = call.Response;

            if (call.VIP == 1) { chkVIP.Checked = true; } else { chkVIP.Checked = false; }
            if (call.ThreatCall == 1) { chkThreat.Checked = true; } else { chkThreat.Checked = false; }
            if (call.FollowUp == 1) { chkFollowUp.Checked = true; } else { chkFollowUp.Checked = false; }
            if (call.EscalationRequired == 1) { chkEscalation.Checked = true; } else { chkEscalation.Checked = false; }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Also... 
I have tried doing this several other ways, without parameters, in different locations, etc. The problem is `main.gridView1.GetFocusedRow()` returns null. Also, running it as a series of methods from the main form does not work either (`gridView1.GetFocusedRow()` is also null).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

In Edit.cs you do

```
    Main main = new Main(); 
    Object obj = main.gridView1.GetFocusedRow();
```

this will create a new Main without displaying it and then try to get an obj from a gridView obviously emtpy.
The same error is repeated in all the code shown.
Also, it's very confused the creation and use of CallLog instances.

Comment: This seems to be the problem. I am creating a new form on that first line which doesn't contain anything. However I can't pass Main into the constructor for Main... Can you reference an article with a solution? I tried Googling "c# preserve main form", not many results...

CallLog is a class with attributes. I use `as CallLog;` because GetFocusedRow() method returns an object, and I have to cast it to a CallLog object.

Comment: If this is the main form of your application and you know it for sure that only one instance of the main form can be instantiated within the application life-time, I suggest that you add a static public property in the Program class, wich return a main form instance that you show via the Application.Run method. This way, you will be able to access the main form instance at any time using this static property.

Comment: Can't make a public static Main instance in Program.cs before `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` is run; it returns an exception. If you put it after, but before App.run, can't make it public and thus useless.

Comment: Ok, I declared it before the line and instantiated it after, I didn't get the exception but `main.gridView1.GetFocusedRow()` is still null in Edit.cs which is the root of the problem.

Comment: Umm Nevermind last comment it did work. I got the object fine when I called Program.main from the edit class. My problem now is that my code is very badly structured with forms and such so I may have to start all over... oh well!